# hiding a div after submitting a form using jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, hide

I am using a onclick function on my form submit button to hide a div. but it is not hiding. what is the best way to do this? I want to hide a div on my page, after submitting a form.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="submit" onclick="hide_group_posts();">
</form>

<div id='div_i_want_to_hide'>
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."page.php";?>
</div>

<script>
function hide_group_posts(){
$('#div_i_want_to_hide').hide();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using ajax to submit the form?

Comment: Maybe it's because the `hide_group_posts` was declared after the button? Anyway don't use inline code if you're using jQuery.

Comment: i am not using ajax to submit the form, must i use ajax?

Comment: If you're not using ajax then you'll have to detect that the form was submitted server side and then hide #div_i_want_to_hide.

Comment: @gdoron i typed alert($) and i got a message that was not undefined. it said the jquery object is actually just the init constructor. so i dont think the issue is with not having a jquery reference

Comment: @Musa. I didn't get your comment, that wasn't true... :) Sorry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $('#div_i_want_to_hide').hide();  
});
```

---

If it didn't help you, one of the following must be true:

- You didn't reference the jQuery library.
- You didn't wrap the code with the DOM ready event.
- You got typos.
- The submit function worked, and you got new page, because you didn't prevent the default.

Prevent it like this:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    $('#div_i_want_to_hide').hide();  
    e.preventDefault();
    // Or with: return false;        
});
```

Comment: i tried this and it is not working. by the way, i am not using ajax to submit the form, so must i use ajax for this to work?

Comment: Yes use ajax to submit form otherwise i don't think there is any reason of hiding div when you submit form.

Comment: @arboles. Cool I was glad to help. Don't forget to accept an answer(this one, or write one yourself if mine didn't help).